# Camera app without interface and button listener

Tags: android, background, camera

I want to develop a custom Android App that use the phone camera to take pictures, but I don't want to see any interface in the app, just run it in background and wait for a default trigger, like push volumen up or down.

Is this possible? Can I run a camera intent in the background?

Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScreenCapture . Check, it might helps

Comment: @Soham I don't want an screenshot, I want a photo from the camera, taken without knowledge for the user

Comment: check out this library - https://github.com/kevalpatel2106/android-hidden-camera